# How can I check if a root user has ssh'd into my server successfully?

Tags: ssh, authentication, sshd, key-authentication

The following code gives all Accepted but doesn't filter out by user name

```
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep Accepted
```

Comment: Surely you don't just need to pipe the result through `grep root`? So please provide an example of what you're wanting as a result

Answer (score 2):

Add the username to the grep pattern?

```
# grep -e "Accepted .* for root " /var/log/auth.log
May  3 23:09:01 lumi sshd[21046]: Accepted publickey for root from 1.2.3.4 port 44308 ssh2
May  6 21:25:20 lumi sshd[6642]: Accepted publickey for root from 1.2.3.4 port 44556 ssh2
```

Or use `last`, which reads `/var/log/wtmp`, that contains a log of the sessions started. Note that noninteractive sessions aren't stored here.

```
# last root
root     pts/38       somehost.somewhere  Sat May  6 21:25   still logged in   
root     pts/3        somehost.somewhere  Wed May  3 23:09 - 23:09  (00:00)
```

At least the location of those logs may be system/distribution specific.

---

However, since we're talking about root logins, it might be good to note that anyone with root powers may edit the logs to hide their logins, so if you're doing this for auditing, you *must* have logging to an external system.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the last command would help you list root logins? In this example, the last command shows that root logged in from the machine with IP address 10.1.57.140 using pseudo terminal 3 (pts/3) on Wednesday, January 11. While last does not clearly state SSH, pts/3 may be a strong indication that the connection was made using SSH.

```
[root@server1 ~]# last
john.doe  pts/0        server1.example.com  Thu Jan 12 12:04  still logged in
root      pts/3        10.1.57.140          Wed Jan 11 12:54 - 13:13  (00:19)
reboot    system boot  3-10-0-327.e17.x     Wed Jan 11 12:52 - 13:10  (00:01)
. . .
```